# Submitting SMAPI application with manifest support

Tags: sonos

Where do I provide the manifest url when submitting a new SMAPI integration? The field for providing a manifest url is non existent.

[image]

Comment: Please email us at developer-feedback@sonos.com with your company information and we'll work with you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a manifest file URL, enter it in the String Resource XML File field. See the **Application review and validation** section of [Submit your service](https://developer.sonos.com/build/content-service-get-started/submit-your-content-service/) for details.